# How to appear online using stanza.io client and ejabberd server?

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, stanza.io

I'm having a problem to appear online at ejabberd, I'm doing a chat client for a customer and I have this part of the code:

```
client.connect();
client.on('session:started', () => {
    client.getRoster()
    client.sendPresence();
    onConnect();
});
```

When I get session started event I send my presence to the server to appear "online" to other users, but it doesn't work, does the name of the event is wrong? The other functionalities work fine I can send message but only in a offline state. Any tips? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your other client has also [sent their presence](https://github.com/legastero/stanza.io/issues/129) and the other user is [subscribed](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0162.html#intro-oversub) to your presence.

Comment: Im using psi to debug with the client, if I understand it right I need to subscribe to see if the user is online, even if the client send the presence? I'll try to subscribe to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You need to send your presence to the server

```
this.client.on('session:started', () => {
        this.client.enableCarbons(err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Server does not support carbons', err);
        }
    });
    this.client.sendPresence();
    });
```

On saving any new user, we need to subscribe that user

```
this.client.subscribe(id);
```

and opposite user has to accept the subscription wheneven they receive presence type as **subscribe**

```
this.client.acceptSubscription(id)
```

Comment: We can send subscribe and acceptSubscription together also

Comment: yeah...we can do that also